# Microsoft Band SDK Preview - NotificationManager within a backgroundtask

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-band

Hi I am not sure if I am missing something or whether this is not within the API which seems short sighted in my opinion.

Can the SDK send a notification to the band from within a background task? This seems to be one of the most useful things to me but when I try I get an error. 'bandClient.NotificationManager.SendMessageAsync' is where it throws an exception. The background task is a timer task.

The background code is simple, I tried it on a background and UI thread.

try

```
            {

                // Get the list of Microsoft Bands paired to the phone.

                IBandInfo[] pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();

                if (pairedBands.Length < 1)

                {

                    deferral.Complete();

                }


                // Connect to Microsoft Band.

                using (IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))

               {


                    await bandClient.NotificationManager.SendMessageAsync(myTileId, "Earnings", currentDollars.ToString(), DateTimeOffset.Now, f);

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
```

Exception and stack trace:

> ex = {System.Exception: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
>
> at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.get_Current()
>
> at Microsoft.Band.BandClientManager.d__2.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location...
>
> at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.get_Current()
>
> at Microsoft.Band.BandClientManager.d__2.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>
> at
>   WindowsRuntimeComponent1.AppTileUpdater.d__8.MoveNext()

Comment: Are you able to connect to the device at all?

Comment: good question, yes I can. So my app is simple, background task and a windows phone app. The windows phone app connects to the band just fine, adds a tile and can send notifications.


If I use the same code within the backgroundtask to connect and send a notification the connect fails.


I do have the appxmanifest set with the rfcomm permissions for both too, nuget added them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the intention is that you should be able to connect to and manipulate a Band from a background task.  However, there is a known issue with the Band SDK Preview (1.3.10219-preview) that prevents the creation of an IBandClient in code running within a background task.

Comment: Thank you, where is the best place to discuss such issues and see known bugs? Also do we have a date for the next release which I assume will fix this?

Comment: That is funny, I was told stackoverflow is the official place for Microsoft Band SDK discussion!

Comment: Phil, is this due to the shared programming model for background tasks for win store and wp81 winrt? I noticed the SDK has a dll that uses this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.rfcommdeviceservice.device.aspx which is not supported by win store when subscribing to sensors. Would you know when a fix will be rolled out?

Comment: No, the background task issue was just an unfortunate side-effect of a last-minute fix in the Preview release to avoid issues with existing Band connections when the application is suspended.  That issue will be fixed prior to the official release of the SDK.  Otherwise, I can't comment about specific timelines.

Answer (score 0):

Backgroundtasks (and quite a few more things) have been sorted in the new release which took the SDK out of preview today.